# Does change in ASPX. CS page requires building.

Tags: asp.net, iis

During my previous projects, any change that I would make to an aspx.cs didnt require building the entire solution. The changes would directly reflect in my IIS hosted server i.e in localhost. 
the new web application has the same setup configured. The application has been added in IIS with a designated Application pool and when browsed the site opens. But in this project, I have to build the solution everytime I make change in aspx.cs page. The same doesn't apply to aspx changes. 
Any help would be appreciated in letting know this difference in behaviour and solution of not building the entire solution if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Web projects Asp.Net only detects changes in aspx, but not cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787727/with-web-projects-asp-net-only-detects-changes-in-aspx-but-not-cs-files)

Comment: That's by design.

Comment: that answer my questions very well. the difference lies in knowing what is web projects and web application project. Thanks @lex                  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx#summary_of_differences